# Find closure of topologist's comb

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Find the closure and limit points of $C=\{(x,0)|x \in [0,1]\} \cup \bigcup\limits_{i \in \mathbb{N}}\{(\frac{1}{n},y)|y \in [0,1]\} $

Would this be the correct closure/limit points for this set?

My attempt:
Every point of $C$ is a limit point, since for each $(x,y) \in C$ and $\epsilon>0$, $B((x,y),\epsilon)-\{(x,y)\} \cap C \neq \varnothing$.Thus if $C'$ is the set of limit points, $C \subset C'$. For each $y \in [0,1]$, the set of points $\{(\frac{1}{n},y)|n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ have a first coordinate that forms a sequence $(\frac{1}{n})$, converging to $0$. Then because each neighborhood of a point $(0,y), y\in [0,1]$ contains some point in $\{(\frac{1}{n},y)|n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, $\{(0,y)|y \in [0,1]\} \subset C'$.So $\bar C=C\cup \{(0,y)|y \in [0,1]\}$.

Edit:I gave the proof of this an attempt, here is my try.

Every point in $(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}) \times [0,1]$ is not a limit point. Let $(x,y) \in (\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}) \times [0,1]$. Choose $\epsilon=\text{min}\{x-\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}-x\}$. Then $B((x,y),\epsilon) \cap C =\varnothing.$ Similarly, any point $(x,y)$ in the lower half plane is not a limit point. Choose $0<\epsilon<|y|$.Every point $(x,y)$ in the left half plane is not a limit point. Choose $0<\epsilon<|x|$.Any point satisfying $x>1$ is not a limit point, choose $0<\epsilon<x-1$. Any point satisfying $y>1$ is not a limit point, choose $0<\epsilon<y-1$.

Comment: Your answer is correct. To prove it consider a point $p$ that is not in $C \cup \{(0, y)\mid y \in [0, 1]\}$ and try to find a neighbourhood of $p$ that does not meet $C$.

Comment: You can even explicitly express the complement of your closure as an open set: it is the union of the open half-planes $\Bbb R\times(\leftarrow,0)$, $(\leftarrow,0)\times\Bbb R$, $\Bbb R\times(1,\to)$, and $(1,\to)\times\Bbb R$ with the open sets $\left(\frac1{n+1},\frac1n\right)\times(0,\to)$ for $n\in\Bbb Z^+$.

Comment: @RobArthan would I only need to consider the cases where $x \in (\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}), y \in [0,1]$?

Comment: @RobArthan for any $p=(x,y) \in (\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n})\times [0,1]$ how about $\epsilon=\text{min}\{x-\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}-x\}$?

Comment: @RobArthan I tried the proof, given your help, is this what you were getting at with a proof?

Comment: Looks good to me.